# error CS0139 shown even i have added the brackets

Tags: c#, break

It stated that there's an error in  every break command
I don't know whether it's a bug or something

I tried to add on a bracket, but the error still can't be solved

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GPAAvg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int score;
        int courses = 0;
        int GPA;
        double sumGPA = 0;
        string msg = "代碼  成績  學分數 Grade GPA積點 ";

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TxtCode.MaxLength = 4;
            TxtScore.MaxLength = 3;
            TxtHour.MaxLength = 1;

        }

        private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            score = Convert.ToInt32(TxtScore.Text);
            string grade;
            switch (score / 10)
            {
        case10:
        case9:
        case8:
            GPA = 4;
            grade = "A";
            break;
        Case7:
            GPA = 3;
            grade = "B";
            break;
        case6:
            GPA = 2;
            grade = "C";
            break;
        case5:
            GPA = 1;
            grade = " D";
            break;
            default:
            GPA = 0;
            grade = "E";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the program can be run because I have already added the brackets and form an enclosing loop. Plz help me to solve the problem . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your end brackets have closed the switch, method, and class, but you've not closed the namespace.

Also, case statements have spaces before the value